# Android Studio automatically uninstalls the app I'm trying to develop

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Android Studio Giraffe installed itself without my permission and screwed everything up. One of its bugs is that it keeps erasing the app I'm developing from its tablet.

How do I get the app to stay in the tablet? Android Studio uninstalls it when the wind blows. (For you juniors, that means when I run tests or try to manually operate the app)

I also wrote the issue up here because I can't tell if it's a bug or a feature:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/296333695

---

creating and testing a new blank app also has the bug. After running a test case the app disappears and must be reinstalled.

Reverting Android-Studio to Flamingo and reverting the Gradle Plugin to 8.0.2 fixed the problem. I could not figure out which one has the bug because I can't downgrade the two versions independently

Answer (score 2):

When running tests on Android, the tests generally interact with the app in a real device or emulator, after the test execution is complete, the application's state is generally restored to its original state, uninstalling APKs that were installed during the test (not always the case).

But If you want to keep the APK installed on your tablet you have to install it by hand or via `adb` command.

I recommend using this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21785770/6817463

```bash
adb install myapp.apk
```

Comment: sry the system left the app installed in the tablet for 4 years before Giraffe came along. I'm not a newb using the editor wrong. Tests are supposed to run without uninstalling the app at the end, and I am aware of the test isolation issues involved